# Need help to solve this math question when x reach 0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

My son can home and ask me to help him with this equation:

lim   ((x-2)/(2x-1))^(1/x)

x→0

I try to use /www.symbolab.com but its too complicated to solve this.

Thanks with the help

Comment: I suggest you try [math.se].  This site is for Mathematica software issues.

Comment: The limit does not exist, by the way.

Comment: Try W|A: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20((x-2)%2F(2x-1))%5E(1%2Fx)%20as%20x%20-%3E%200 - I think it gives enough information to help you explain it.  Or for $x \approx 0$, the function is approximately $(2^\pm)^{1/x}$, which is probably like a textbook example.

Answer (score 1):

`Limit[(x - 2)/(2 x - 1)^(1/x), x -> 0]` produces `-2 E^(2 + 2 I Interval[{0, \[Pi]}])`

This is a highly oscillatory function near the origin, much like `Sin[1/x]`. To plot the function try `Plot[Re[(x - 2)/(2 x - 1)^(1/x)], {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Black}]`.

[image]